# Clearing DNS Cache in Linux

Tags: linux, dns

I work on Linux on my laptop, I could not access a particular website using the URL, so I used `sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart` in order to clear the DNS cache, but the URL is still throws 'Server Not Found' in Firefox. I have tried also Chrome, it still not working. Other friends can see the web page, but I can not. So what would be the main cause of this? I can surf other sites nicely.

Weirdly enough when I even try the IP address of that particular URL, it shows me a different page than what other people see.

I appreciate any help on this matter.

Comment: Does `host www.strangesite.co.uk` return the IP you expect? (Showing different content when you go there via the IP is not unusual, it's called name-based virtual hosting.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz the IP has a default page coming from cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi, but when I use the main URL, no browser in my laptop shows anything except throwing errors that they couldn't connect to the server.

Comment: Have you checked your `/etc/hosts` file to make sure you aren't redirecting the hostname or IP address?

Comment: checked the file and here is what it has:'127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 ---name-VGN-model-N

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters'

Comment: Ping the website from the working machine, what IP do you get? Ping the website from the laptop, is it the same IP? Does it resolve? What happens if you take DNS out of the equation? Try pinging the IP from the working machine directly on the laptop. What happens? If you get a response on the IP only on the laptop try entering that into the browser address bar. What happens?

Comment: Restart does not automatically clear the cache. That depends on the distribution. `nscd -i hosts` will work on all major distributions I know of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you are running `bind` by accident you should check your `nscd` configuration file located at `/etc/nscd.conf`.

It will list the caches that are kept.

```
 enable-cache            hosts           yes
 positive-time-to-live   hosts           3600
 .......
```

`# nscd -?`

`-g, --statistics           Print current configuration statistics`

`-i, --invalidate=TABLE     Invalidate the specified cache`

`nscd -g`

```
    hosts cache:

        yes  cache is enabled
         no  cache is persistent
        yes  cache is shared
        211  suggested size
     216064  total data pool size
        384  used data pool size
        600  seconds time to live for positive entries
          0  seconds time to live for negative entries
          0  cache hits on positive entries
          0  cache hits on negative entries
        128  cache misses on positive entries
          0  cache misses on negative entries
          0% cache hit rate
          3  current number of cached values
          7  maximum number of cached values
          2  maximum chain length searched
          0  number of delays on rdlock
          0  number of delays on wrlock
          0  memory allocations failed
        yes  check /etc/{hosts,resolv.conf} for changes
```

`# nscd -i hosts`

This will invalidate the cache.

But, after doing it there was no change to the hosts entries in `nscd -g`
After restarting `nscd` it was flushed.

`service nscd restart`

```
    hosts cache:

        yes  cache is enabled
         no  cache is persistent
        yes  cache is shared
        211  suggested size
     216064  total data pool size
          0  used data pool size
        600  seconds time to live for positive entries
          0  seconds time to live for negative entries
          0  cache hits on positive entries
          0  cache hits on negative entries
          0  cache misses on positive entries
          0  cache misses on negative entries
          0% cache hit rate
          0  current number of cached values
          0  maximum number of cached values
          0  maximum chain length searched
          0  number of delays on rdlock
          0  number of delays on wrlock
          0  memory allocations failed
        yes  check /etc/{hosts,resolv.conf} for changes
```

Unless you are running bind this is the only way to clear the cache short of finding the database for `nscd` and deleting it which could cause other issues. I would follow the troubleshooting procedures for IP resolution. I outlined some in the comments to your question.

This is a link to a pretty good Linux Journal article on [Troubleshooting Network Problems](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/troubleshooting-network-problems).

Comment: This is great. Thank you, it worked like a charm now. Now I can comfortably visit my site. Nice help.

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old question, but adding this in case someone is facing this issue again.

When I faced a similar DNS client cache issue this morning, I did all the regular steps to clear the cache stored by `nscd` and as mentioned in the first answer, restarted `nscd`. I even dropped the OS cache, but a certain hostname was still resolving to the old IP address. It started resolving only after I removed the `nameserver 127.0.0.1` line from resolv.conf.