# round robin for curl and dnsmasq

Tags: curl, dnsmasq, round-robin

I have setup dnsmasq to the basic configuration, pointing a file with two IP addresses.

```
10.0.0.1 a.b.c
10.0.0.2 a.b.c
```

When I do nslookup or dig on a.b.c, I see round robin seems to be in effect (as I would expect since as far as I know round robin is the default in dnsmasq).  But when I curl or ping a.b.c, I always get the same response. The obvious first response is that the response is being cached, but from what I can tell, curl does not cache the response and when you use the -v flag for curl the first line printed is something like "cache missed".

So what I am wondering is: am I doing something wrong in my setup? Is there somewhere else that the caching could possibly be happening? I can provide exact files or more info, but I'm currently a bit lost as to why I don't see the rotating happening.

Answer (score 1):

Curl uses getaddrinfo() which uses a system caching mechanism, for a detailed description of the process, please see the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17938429/3331838

[wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html), describes this a bit more in detail in the no-dns-cache option

```
Please note that this option will not affect caching that might be performed by the resolving library or by an external caching layer, such as NSCD. 

If you don’t understand exactly what this option does, you probably won’t need it.
```

What you likely need to do is force the ncsd server to invalidate any cache between requests with

```
nscd -i hosts
```

or disable caching completely (not sure what issues this may cause), see the following answer for details on this

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34665/191614